# DocuSign REST API: Revoke token - Error "The presented token is invalid"

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to use the revoke functionality but I'm always getting as reply "The presented token is invalid".

```
URL: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/revoke
Token: PVpA/I45bTLznv8DipLhGitwUxxx
```

I tried the following requests but none of them is working:

```
{
"uri": "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth2/revoke",
"method": "POST",
"muteHttpExceptions": true,
"body": "token=PVpA%2FI45bTLznv8DipLhGitwUxxx",
"headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication": "IntegratorKey=TEST-9229b096-4390-48db-b6cc-xxxxxxxxx",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   }
}
```

the above request being like what is suggested in iodocs.docusign.com

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "muteHttpExceptions": true,
  "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer PVpA/I45bTLznv8DipLhGitwUxxx" }
}
```

Also changing "/" with "%2F" in the token doesn't change anything.

Does someone know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following base-uri: https://account-d.docusign.com